Is it advisable to show a bottom sheet after a feedback snackbar?
Is it advisable to show a bottom sheet after a feedback snackbar?
The case would be submitting feedback and then after the snackbar disappears show a bottom sheet to redirect user to a different screen to take an action.

is this for mobile?

Yes, for mobile

What do you mean with possible? Possible to implement, or advisable from UX point of view?

Advisable from UX point of view

It depends on the information or interactions provided on the current page with the submit feedback form.
In general, consider this:

User hits submit feedback
A snackbar appears then fades out
A permanent bottom sheet appears
hitting the bottom sheet option redirects to other page

Alternative:

User hits submit feedback
User is redirected to other page

In the first example the feedback to the user is inconsequent. The snackbar is something temporal/intermediate and could be left out and the bottom sheet displayed directly - but a bottom sheet is more of a menu and does not have a prompt text - therefore a banner is maybe what you actually need. Additionally you should ask yourself why it is necessary to leave the user on the screen with the submit feedback form and provide the option to manually leave the screen.
The second example shows a consequent flow but this one requires (as a good thing) that the submit feedback form is the only content on the screen and there is no reason to stay on that screen after hitting submit.
